# JQuery Set tab to "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

How can I modify this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/P33Cj/) so that it will:

a) highlight the active `<li>`

b) Make it possible to activate a tab content at page load (a tab is already opened when the page is loaded for the first time)

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $panels = $('.panels > .panel');
$('#menu > li').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $panels.filter('.'+this.id).trigger('togglePanel');
});
$panels
    .on('togglePanel', function(){
        var $this           =   $(this)
          , $activePanels   =   $panels.filter(':visible').not($this);
        if ($activePanels.length) {
            $activePanels
                .one('panelHidden', function(){
                    $this.is(':visible')
                    ? $this.trigger('hidePanel')
                    : $this.trigger('showPanel');
                })
                .trigger('hidePanel');
        } else {
            $this.is(':visible')
            ? $this.trigger('hidePanel')
            : $this.trigger('showPanel');
        }
    })
    .on('hidePanel', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $this.animate({
                'width': 'hide'
            }, 1000, function(){
                $this.trigger('panelHidden');
            });
        });
    })
    .on('showPanel', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            'width': 'show'
        }, 1000, function() {
            $this.find('.content').fadeIn(500, function(){
                $this.trigger('panelShown');
            });
        });
    });
$panels.find('.content .close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel').trigger('togglePanel');
});
```

});

Comment: I don't understand b), but for a) I would suggest you to make a style for the active li element with a class name e.g. 'active' and set the li element's class to that onclick.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/P33Cj/71/ If that's it, i could make answer... :)

Comment: Just 3 lines of code :) http://jsfiddle.net/w4b94g1a/ (applied to `hidePanel` event, so that it removes `.active` class automatically on "unclick" menu and on click "X")